# Microsoft Word 2016 - Footnote separator

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Microsoft Word 2016. I have problem with formatting of footnote. There is a break row between the line and the footnote itself which can be clearly seen on the screen bellow.

[image]

How can I get rid of this line / edit its style?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to View tab
2. Select "Draft" view option
3. Go to References tab
4. Select "Show Notes"
5. Select "Footnote Separator" from the dropdown list